# 複数のファイルを読み取り、For（ループ）で簡潔に書きたいです。

Tags: python, python3, pandas

以下のファイルがあります：

```
group01/data/area01.csv
group01/data/area02.csv
group01/data/area03.csv

group02/data/area01.csv
group02/data/area02.csv
group02/data/area03.csv

group03/data/area01.csv
group03/data/area02.csv
group03/data/area03.csv

group04/data/area03.csv
group05/data/area03.csv
```

**実現したい動作:**

- area01と02の場合、group1 group2 group3 のファイルをループ(for)で読み取る
- area03の場合、group1 group2 group3 group4 group5のファイルをループ(for)で読み取る

以下は現状のコードです。もっと簡潔な書き方はありますか？ご教授頂けると幸いです。

```py
folder1 = ['01\data\area01','02\data\area01','03\data\area01']
folder2 = ['01\data\area02','02\data\area02','03\data\area02']
folder3 = ['01\data\area03','02\data\area03','03\data\area03','04\data\area03','05\data\area03']

for folder in folders:
    group_files =[]
    for file in folder:
        group_files += [r"group"+str(file)+".csv"]
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(file, header=[0, 1]) for file in group_files]
```

Comment: 「group02/data/area02.csv」が２つありますが書き間違いで実際は別のファイルがあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。修正しました

Answer (score 1):

簡潔かどうかは判りませんが、glob で `area01.csv`, `area02.csv`, `area03.csv` をそれぞれで収集してもよいかと思います。

```py
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

area_id = [1, 2, 3]
dfs = {}
for aid in area_id:
    area = f'area{aid:02d}'
    group_files = sorted(glob(f'group0[1-5]/data/{area}.csv'))
    dfs[area] = [pd.read_csv(file, header=[0, 1]) for file in group_files]

print(dfs['area01'])
print(dfs['area02'])
print(dfs['area03'])
```

Comment: そもそもの問題は書き間違いので、いまは修正しました。この答えは変更がないんですか？

Comment: 修正後のファイルパスは想定通りでしたので変更はありません。

Answer (score 1):

> area01と02の場合、group1 group2 group3 のファイルをループ(for)で読み取る
> area03の場合、group1 group2 group3 group4 group5のファイルをループ(for)で読み取る

カレントディレクトリーから対象の CSVファイルを探索する
`read_csv`の順序は `ser`の順序なので, 必要であれば `sort`を

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

curr = Path('.')
ser = pd.DataFrame([
    {'stem': f.stem, 'path': f}for f in curr.glob('group??/data/area??.csv')
]).groupby('stem').agg(list).iloc[:, 0]

# area01 の場合
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=[0, 1])for f in ser['area01']]

# area03 の場合
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=[0, 1])for f in ser['area03']]
```

Answer (score -1):

ファイル名、ってのは文字列です。
文字列操作で、group01、group02、group03、group04、group05、とforループでこれらの文字列を作るにはどうするのかを考えてみよう。
これができるなら、同様に、area01.csv、area02.csv、area03.csv、という文字列を作る方法を考えてみればいいかと。